# cURL to PHP with header and username but without password

Tags: php, curl, header, passwords

I've been trying and researching very hard but I haven't found an answer.

I got following cURL:

```
curl "https://someurl" -H "client-id: Fsomemorecharacters8=" -u "8somemorecharacters0:"
```

Testing in a command shell works perfectly.
But how can I get it to work with PHP?
Usually its "username:password" but I got "username:" which is strange.

My PHP Code so far:

```
<?php
  $ch = curl_init();
  $url = 'https://someurl';

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, array('client-id: FHP20c+somemorecharacters8='));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, '85a15somemorecharacters4550:'); //Issue is here i think

  $output = curl_exec($ch);

  curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Do you have any idea how to make it work given -u "username:" instead of -u "username:password"?

Regards

**UPDATE**
See below for the answer!

Comment: Is the space at the end of `'85a15somemorecharacters4550: '` a typo? That'll be sending a single space as the password.

Comment: thank you for your answer @iainn.
Sorry, that was a typo. I edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to solve it after all.

1. Thanks to `print curl_error($ch);` right after `$output = curl_exec($ch);` i found out that there is a "SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain".
2. So I needed to download the certificate and to include it in the request like so: `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__)."/cacert-2017-09-20.pem");` Or you could use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` which is, however, not recommended.
3. Thanks to echoing `$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);` I found out that my headers were missing. I need to use `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` instead of `CURLOPT_HEADER`.

So here is my full code:

```
<?php

  $ch = curl_init();
  $url = 'https://someurl';

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__)."/cacert-2017-09-20.pem");
  //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('client-id: client-id: FHP20c+somemorecharacters8='));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, '885a15somemorecharacters4550:');

  $output = curl_exec($ch);
  print curl_error($ch);
  $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  

  curl_close($ch);

  file_put_contents('output.txt', $output);

  echo '<br><b>Output</b><br>' . $output;
  echo '<br><b>Status-Code</b><br>' . $status_code;
?>
```